# How to compare 2 dates with each other. Dates are converted to String

Tags: swift, date, tableview

I want to sort my tableview on date. I know I can do that by using:

```
    array.sort {
        $0.date! < $1.date!
    }
```

Problem is that the date is converted to a String. The date is saved in core data and changing the attribute date to NSDate is causing problems. SO how can I compare the dates without changing my Core Data?

Comment: convert them to `NSDate` dynamically or create a transient property

Comment: convert your 'dd-MM-yyyy' formated String to 'yyyyMMdd' format and sort by Number like 20161022 > 20160923

Answer (score 1):

> Update for swift 3 :

if you want to compare date objects, used below lines of code:

```
extension Date {

    func isGreater(than date: Date) -> Bool {
        return self >= date
    }

    func isSmaller(than date: Date) -> Bool {
        return self < date
    }

    func isEqual(to date: Date) -> Bool {
        return self == date
    }
}
```

// how to call it?

```
 let isGreater = end_date.isGreater(than: start_date)
```

// where end_date and start_date is your date objects.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to sort by strings, what is your string date format?
Here is an example of sorting dates with strings:

```
let date1 = Date()

let date2 = Date().addingTimeInterval(TimeInterval.abs(60.0))

let date3 = Date().addingTimeInterval(TimeInterval.abs(60 * 60 * 24))

var arrayOfDates = [date1.description, date2.description, date3.description]

let sorted = arrayOfDates.sorted { $0.0 > $0.1 }

print(sorted.first!)
print(sorted[1])
print(sorted[2])

output:
 2016-10-31 18:33:32 +0000
 2016-10-30 18:34:32 +0000
 2016-10-30 18:33:32 +0000
```

switching sorted to:

```
let sorted = arrayOfDates.sorted { $0.0 < $0.1 }

gives the following outside:

2016-10-30 18:35:58 +0000
2016-10-30 18:36:58 +0000
2016-10-31 18:35:58 +0000
```

Comment: This method only works with the days if you take for example 22-10-2016 and 23-09-2016 then it will put 22-10-2016 first. The date format I have used for my Strings is: dd-MM-yyyy